# Gmail Canned Response with data from Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gmail

Some context:
I have a few canned responses on my business email setup to autoreplay. Such as if someone emails my business email with the word price in the subject, my Gmail will send out a canned response listing my most common prices.

Problem:
Now if I ever have a price change I have to go and edit this canned response, which in it's self is not hard. However, it could be something I accidently forget to do when updating the prices in my master price spreadsheet.

Solution I'm Looking for:
Is there any code I can add to my email that pulls data from the cells in my spreadsheet. The cell location of my prices should never change, so if I had a way to pull that cell from the spreadsheet I'd only have to change my spreadsheet and the canned response will pull the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to manage or edit Canned Responses from the API or Apps Script. There is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139467023) which you can support by clicking on the top-left star next to the issue number to give more priority to the request and to receive updates.

The only workaround would be creating the emails in a separate Spreadsheet and sending them from there.